# Parallel.ForEach race condition

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am periodically getting into what I think is a race condition within a parallel.ForEach loop. I say this because it always hangs on that part of the code.

```
try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.tracex", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly), _po, (path, ls) =>
        {
            DebugFile file;
            if (filterDate)
            {
                if (filterUser)
                {
                    file = new DebugFile(path, startTime, endTime, user);
                }
                else file = new DebugFile(path, startTime, endTime);
            }
            else if (filterUser)
            {
                file = new DebugFile(path, user);
            }
            else file = new DebugFile(path);
            if (!file.IsFiltered()) 
            {
                _files.Add(file);
            }
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _loadCount);  // increment how many we've checked
            if (_po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ls.Break();
            }
        });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(oce.ToString());
}
```

In my _files object, I am handling locking when calling the Add method.

```
public virtual void Add(T item)
{
    _lock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        _bindingList.Add(item);
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
    OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemAdded, _bindingList.Count - 1));
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? It doesn't hang every time, just intermittently. Also, at least for me, it doesn't happen the first time I call the code. It only happens if I call it once, then call it again, typically the second or third time.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I realized that I'm using a custom task scheduler. When I remove that, I don't see anymore hangs. I did this so I could customize how many threads I was running. My thinking being that since I'm mostly reading files over a network, the IO would slow things down so I could run more tasks at once. Here is how I've constructed the scheduler:

```
public class TaskSchedulerForSlowIO : TaskScheduler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// maximum number of tasks to run concurrently
    /// </summary>
    private int _maxConcurrencyLevel;

    /// <summary>
    /// lock for reading tasks array
    /// </summary>
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _listLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    /// <summary>
    /// list of tasks running
    /// </summary>
    private LinkedList<Task> _tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor - This will increase threadpool limits if necessary
    /// </summary>
    public TaskSchedulerForSlowIO()
        : base()
    {
        _maxConcurrencyLevel = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10;
        int workerThreads, ioThreads, minimumConcurrency;
        minimumConcurrency = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
        if (workerThreads < _maxConcurrencyLevel)
        {
            if (ioThreads < _maxConcurrencyLevel)
            {
                ioThreads = _maxConcurrencyLevel;
            }
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(_maxConcurrencyLevel, ioThreads);
        }
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
        if (workerThreads < minimumConcurrency)
        {
            if (ioThreads < minimumConcurrency)
            {
                ioThreads = minimumConcurrency;
            }
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(minimumConcurrency, ioThreads);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementing TaskScheduler
    /// </summary>
    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return _maxConcurrencyLevel;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scheduler Implementation
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>ScheduledTasks</returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        Task[] tasks;
        _listLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            tasks = _tasks.ToArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            _listLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Queues the specified task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task to queue</param>
    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        int count;
        _listLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            _tasks.AddLast(task);
            count = _tasks.Count;
        }
        finally
        {
            _listLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
        if (count <= _maxConcurrencyLevel)
        {
            ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(ProcessTask, task);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scheduler Implementation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task to remove</param>
    /// <returns>Success</returns>
    protected override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
    {
        _listLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            return _tasks.Remove(task);
        }
        finally
        {
            _listLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scheduled Implementation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task to execute</param>
    /// <param name="taskWasPreviouslyQueued">Was the task previously queued</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        //We're not going to inline slow IO
        return false;
    }

    void ProcessTask(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            Task t = o as Task;
            if (t != null)
            {
                if (base.TryExecuteTask(t))
                {
                    if(!(t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)) t.Wait();
                    TryDequeue(t);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(AggregateException a)
        {
            var e = a.Flatten();
            foreach (Exception ex in e.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of the `try`/`finally` in the `Add` method. Catch-all exception handling makes debugging very difficult. Do that and see if anything gets thrown.

Comment: @Enigmativity `try/finally` doesn't mean *Catch-all exception* It is just to make sure `_lock.ExitWriteLock();` is executed.

Comment: griztown, What do you get when you replace your method with `lock(aSharedObj)  _bindingList.Add(item);` ?

Comment: What is `_files`? Is that an object of the type having the `Add()` method you show? You should note that if you are writing to the object, _all_ accesses to the object need to be protected; e.g. `_bindingList.Count` is not thread-safe and must be inside the `lock` also. Given the lack of a complete code example, you could have other threading bugs as well. Please provide [a good, minimal, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want a specific answer.

Comment: _files is a class I created that is a sortable binding list. Thus the underlying _bindinglist property of the _files object. So it sounds like I need to lock _files before doing anything in the parallel.ForEach loop?

Answer (score -1):

There may be a lot of reasons about that. 
For example

1) The origin, hence the mutation characteristics of `filterUser`, `filterDate`, `IsFiltered()`...are not clear looking on the code, which may cause a problem.

2) In general the code is non scalable. Avoid accessing (reading) files in parallel, as IO device (hard disk I presume in your case) is no parallel reading device, and you most likely will get worse performance then in case of simple serial processing.

Suggession: Set thread affinity to only 2 threads/cores (I again presume you have more), and debug, to see what happens. Most likely you will get to the point where conflict raises.

Comment: Your post isn't an answer to the question. A suggestion: don't try to answer a question that can't be answered.

Comment: Thanks Tigran.filterUser and filterDate are booleans that tell if we want to filter files based on the associated user or the date/time it was created. IsFiltered is a flag on the DebugFile class that gets set if the file should be filtered. I'll test out the other suggestions.

Comment: I set the threads to 8 (I have 4 cores) and it now hangs every time. But I still can't see why. Any ideas who to debug this?

Comment: I figured out the source of the issue, a custom task scheduler. I added the code up above. If anything jumps out at you, let me know.

Comment: why you write `_maxConcurrencyLevel = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10;` ?You expect running 10 threads per core ?

Comment: And more, adding more threads for reading files, doesn't necessary significantly increases a performance as you still need to read a file, and hard disk is not a parallel reading device, so there are a lot of interrupts happening inside. I would simply suggest: do not customize @griztown number of threads, but relay on the amount of threads generated by TPL automatically (tending to match the number of cores). Also pay attention on *how* you read a file. Especially, if it is on network location (so you have IO time + network latency + access permission on read), read all at once in a buffer

Comment: @griztown ads after process it. If you do not do it already like that, would suggest to change your code. In other words: using multi threading is clever approach, but it is  not a silver bullet for performance, search for performance bottlenecks also in other places of your program.